# Replace all image src from html object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ajax is used to fetched data from a database. It returns an HTML object. In side that object, I need to replace all images src.

Inside of the request success function:

```
[...]
success: function(html) {
      var images = $(html).find("img");
      images.each(function(i, img) {
           var src = <some-url>;
           $(img).attr("src", src)
      }
      console.log(html);
}
```

Image sources are not being replaced in the response HTML. Is there a way to replace all image src?

Comment: can you show us `console.log(html);` before and after `each` loop?

Comment: `$(html).find('img').attr('src', () => newSrc);`

Comment: @Tushar i think the html which will be returned is in string format.. how will you replace `img` tag int that..??

Comment: @SwapNeil It is already replaced by the `attr` method. This will return jQuery object, string can be obtained from it by using `html()` method on it.

Comment: Your code should work if you close `)` after `each`.

Comment: Why do you want to replace same image url in all existing img tag ?

Comment: To be exact, I'm adding a path to all image so "/foo.jpg" will be changed to "http://www.whatever.com/foo.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

You are directly appending string thus have no effect of manipulation.

Instead create a jQuery object manipulate it then append the manipulated object.

```
var fragment = $(html);

//If all image needs same image url
//fragment.find("img").attr('src', '<some-url>');

fragment.find("img").attr('src', function(_, currentValue){
    return '<some-url>';
}); 

console.log(fragment);
```

Comment: Hi thanks. I need to replace all image src with new path. I need to return a new HTML with the replaced image src.

Comment: @Sylar, `.attr('src', function(_, currentValue){
    return '<some-url>';
})` will the job for you. return the `src` with new path

Comment: I dont think you understand. Inside the html object are images with a src of  `/foo.jpg`. I need to replace that with `/bar.png` then inside the html should have all images with new src.

Comment: @Sylar, I got it mate. `.attr('src', function(_, currentValue){  return '/bar.png;' })` //currentValue will be '/foo.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing bracket in your example. Try the given code:

```js
var images = $("#example").find("img");
 images.each(function(i, img) {
   var src = "<some-url>";
   $(img).attr("src", src)
 });

console.log($("#example").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
  <img src="1">
  <img src="2">
  <img src="3">
</div>
```

The above code snippet changes successfully the src tag of every img element. I hope that helps.